Cannot run Animation Hitches Instrument. Is this a bug?
I'm trying to run the Instrument "Animation Hitches", but it fails immediately after starting on the iPhone. This happens on multiple projects, including a brand new project.
I get the following errors:



Timestamp
Message




(Before Run Started)
Unexpected failure: Couriers have returned unexpectedly.


(Before Run Started)
Failed to start the recording: Failed starting ktrace session.



The issue also happens with the instruments App Launch, but not with any other that I tested.
Is this a bug?
Using Xcode Version 16.1, Mac Mini M1 Sequoia 15.1. Running project on iPhone 14 Pro iOS 18.1.
Also posted on Apple Developer Forums

The problem would appear to be using “Recording mode” of “Deferred” when profiling on a physical iOS device, regardless of which Instruments template you choose. If you change the recording mode to “Capture last n seconds” (or, where available, “Immediate”), this problem does not manifest itself.

This problem jumps out at you when using “Animation hitches” template because that template does not accept a recording mode of “Immediate” and defaults to “Deferred” mode. But if you pick a different template, and manually change its recording mode to “Deferred”, that will also manifest the same problem.
This seems worthy of a bug report.
